# Find the density function from the probability function given by indicator functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Please tell me if this is correct:

Let $X$ be a random variable with probability distribution given by:
[image]

Find the probability density function of $X$.

What I think:

1. In order to determine the density function from the probability function I just need to derivate the probability function with respect to $x$. My only issue is with the derivative of the second indicator function which I think is $0$, please tell me if this is correct.
2. To verify that the density function obtained is in fact a density function I verified the following conditions: $f(x)$ $≥$ $0$ $∀$ $x ∈ R$, $∫f(x)dx = 1$ (over $R$) and $∫f(x)dx = P(a<x≤b)$ $∀$ $a<b$ (integral in the interval $[a,b]$). By doing this I verified that I trully obtained a density function but I don't know if what I did to the second indicator function can be done!
3. In the end I got that the density function is $f(x)=3x^2I[$0,1$](x)$. Is this result correct? If I did the computations correctly it does verify the above requeriments!

Please tell me if my reasoning is correct!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. In order to determine the density function from the probability function I just need to derivate the probability function with respect to $x$. My only issue is with the derivative of the second indicator function which I think is $0$, please tell me if this is correct.

That is correct.

> 2. To verify that the density function obtained is in fact a density function I verified the following conditions: $f(x)$ $≥$ $0$ $∀$ $x ∈ R$, $∫f(x)dx = 1$ (over $R$) and $∫f(x)dx = P(a<x≤b)$ $∀$ $a<b$ (integral in the interval $[a,b]$). By doing this I verified that I trully obtained a density function but I don't know if what I did to the second indicator function can be done!

It can.  $\qquad\displaystyle\int_1^\infty 0~\mathrm d x=0$

> 3. In the end I got that the density function is $f(x)=3x^2I[$0,1$](x)$. Is this result correct? If I did the computations correctly it does verify the above requeriments!

That is correct.